# Reading individual strings in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a program that searches for Spotify songs. I want it to go through an array with a list of songs and search for them individually:

```
songs = ['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
spotifyObject.search(songs)
```

`spotifyObject.search` followed by whatever is in the brackets is how you search for songs, I want to have a loop what searches `'song1'`, then `'song2'` etc. - so essentially replacing the variable in the brackets each time.

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to write such a loop? Did you read this already? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Can you give us some example input/output?

Comment: @mkrieger1 when I made the loop I wasn't sure how to do it, it ended up searching for all the songs in the array. I am just struggling pulling individual strings out of the array, I know how to print them on separate lines, but here I have to change the variable each time

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: In particular, don't vandalize your posts by adding rude text. That's not going to make it any easier for you to get the help you want.

Comment: @cigien apologies.

Comment: No worries, we all get upset sometimes. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you just want to loop though the list...

```
for item in songs:
   spotifyObject.search(item)
```

Comment: Thank you. I mixed some things around and it is now working, the problem was the loop wasn't reading the arrays properly, but I eventually got it working.